# How can I use redux to manage renderScene so that the Component to render is driven by the state?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build a simple react-native app with just 3 scenes: `Home`, `Recent` (recent images), and `Photo` (the photo that is selected in `Recent`)

I am using Navigator:

```
<Navigator
  ref="navigator"
  configureScene={(route) => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottomAndroid;
    }
  }}
  initialRoute={{}}
  renderScene={(route, navigator) => this.renderScene(route, navigator)}
/>
```

And here is the `renderScene`:

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
  if (route === 'home') {
    return (
      <Home
        navigator={navigator}
        />
    );
  }
  if (route === 'Recent') {
    return (
      <Recent
        navigator={navigator}
        />
    );
  }
  if (route === 'Photo') {
    return (
      <Photo
        navigator={navigator}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I realize that `Photo` is dumb and not even receiving a photo or anything - right now I am just trying to finish set up.

Anyway - I am connecting this component to my state so I am connected to my `scene` reducer.  How can I use this now to drive `renderScene`?

Answer (score 0):

I use mobx instead of redux as it supports this out of the box. For redux, you need to use container + dumb components pattern. The container has state that gets passed as props to component. the container's render() and state then drives re-render of dumb component